# How to loop a map with minimum resources?

Tags: java, dictionary

I was looking for a best way to loop through a map that involve as minimum resources as possible. Assume I have an object as the value, and the key is a string that referencing to the object. With the following two loop, may I know which one is better and how did you justified it run only minimum resources?

```
for(Map.Entry<String, MyObject> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
  ...
}

for( String key : myMap.keySet() ) {
  ...
}
```

THanks @!

Comment: Please define "minimum resources", also, have you tested this portion of your program with a profiler and know for certain that it is a critical bottle neck that is slowing your program down? Also are you familiar with one of Donald Knuth's most famous quotes?

Comment: An important choice: do you **need** access to the key and value in the loop? If you *only* need the keys (or *only* need the values) then using `keySet()` (or `values()`) is *usually* more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on which specific `Map` you use. It's impossible to tell as it stands, since `Map` is an interface.

In most map implementations both `entrySet` and `keySet` will return a *view* of the underlying set of entries / keys, so I'd say that they are likely more or less as efficient in all aspects.

Note that if you retrieve all *entries* you're getting the values at the same time. This may save you some time if you often *need* the value.

Comment: `entrySet()` and `keySet()` (as well as `values()`) **must** return a view and modifications to them **must** be reflected back to the original `Map`. One *could* implement those views by creating a copy and synchronizing back-and-forth, but I don't think that any commonly used `Map` does it that way.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following is more efficient:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, MyObject> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
  ...
}
```

This is because it is probably doing a simple iteration over a collection depending on the Map implementation. On the other hand, if you iterate over the key and then call the Map's **get** method using the key, you are not only iterating over a collection of keys but also doing a lookup to retrieve each element from the Map.

Comment: I can provide you with a map where `entrySet` is faaaar worse than going through `keySet` :-)

Comment: No doubt. I think that is why we both qualified our answers with a "depending on the Map". Couple of lawyers here. ;)

Comment: I miss the argument for why `entrySet` is more efficient. `keySet` is probably also doing a simple iteration, right? Of course using `get()` would be slower, but that's not the question...

Comment: Correct, 'keySet' is probably as efficient as 'entrySet'. However, I am making an assumption (I know, I know) that in the key iteration 'get' will probably be called. It the 'value' is never needed, absolutely use 'keySet'.

Comment: @Ishtar StackOverflow question: How do you get the background grey in comments?

Comment: @John B Use Backticks '`', more formatting in comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities

Comment: @aioobe: out of curiosity: which one? Is it a general-purpose `Map` or a specialized one?

Answer (score 2):

For the usual/sensible implementations:

- both loops only create an additional iterator object, so the **memory resources** are about the same (since for sensible implementations, the iterator objects themselves are quite simple).
- the **time resources** depend on what you do in the loop. If you only need the key, they are about the same, too. If you need to retrieve the value from the key, you need slightly more runtime, but I don't think that makes a big difference.
- on the whole, I'd think the differences are so small that it's **premature optimization** if you choose one implementation just because of it's minimal advantage in resources.

Answer (score 1):

What resources do you mean? Memory?

In both cases you have one object reference beng used in the loop - whether it is entry or key. In neither case are other objects created. Both would be more or less equal in performance and resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you worried about resources? Is this honestly a practical, legitimate concern or is it a case of premature optimisation?

From a design point of view, I'd use the entryset if you need to deal with the keys and values rather than just the keys. Not from a performance perspective, but from a practical, design perspective it's clearer that you're doing something with the entries in the map if you use that rather than just the keys. (Of course, if you are just doing something with the keys use the keyset.)

As others have mentioned from a performance perspective it's impossible to tell without knowing implementation details, but unless you're doing something very specific or dealing with massive maps, that shouldn't be an issue.